# how to use cloudant out node with Service External Cloudant or couchdb service?

Tags: node-red

I am facing issue while using Cloudant out node with Service External Cloudant or couchdb service in Node-RED(local).
While deploying flow I am getting error saying "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null**".

And in local Node-RED there is no option to choose **CloundantNoSQLDB** drop-down in cloudant out node(only External Cloudant or couchdb service option is there.).

Please find attached screen shots for reference where both Local and IBM cloud Node-RED cloudant out node drop-down.  enter image description here

[image]